# Cannot get VictoryChart by id, How can I get it by id?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Firstly, I want to download `VictoryChart` by using `file-saver`. So I need to access to VictoryChat by Id but I cannot.

When I try to `console.log(document.getElementById("latestScenariosGraph"))`, it returns NULL.

The code is below:

```
<div className="chart-wrapper">
  <VictoryChart id="latestScenariosGraph"
                height={500} width={1000}
                theme={VictoryTheme.material}
                padding={{top: 50, bottom: 30, left: 125, right: 30}}
                domain={{x: [0, 10], y: [0, 10]}}
  >
    <VictoryScatter
      labelComponent={<VictoryTooltip
        cornerRadius={15}
        pointerLength={75}
        flyoutWidth={260}
        flyoutHeight={100}
        style={{fontSize: '27px'}}
      />}
      style={{ data: {
          fill: "#c43a31",
          stroke: "#000000",
          fillOpacity: 0.7,
          strokeWidth: 3,
          axis: 10
        }, }}
      size={15}
      data={data.mostUsedScenarios.timeScenarioGraphData.map((d) => ({ x: d.name, y: d.date, label: d.name + "\n" + d.date }))}
    />
  </VictoryChart>
</div>
```

I want to access to VictoryChat by id and I wonder where is the problem to return null?

Comment: What HTML does the `<VictoryChart />` component produce? Just because it takes an `id` parameter doesn't mean it actually gets added to the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Try using react ref, instead of native getElementById. Based on victory chart [documentation](https://formidable.com/open-source/victory/docs/common-container-props#containerref), like this:

```js
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.chartRef= React.createRef();
}

downloadChart = () => {
    const node = this.chartRef.current;
    console.log(node);
    // do your download logic
}

render() {
    return (
        <VictoryChart containerRef={(ref) => { this.chartRef = ref; }} />
    )
}
```

**Second options**

If you still want to use getElementById, based on the [documentation](https://formidable.com/open-source/victory/docs/common-container-props#containerid), use `containerId` props.

```
<VictoryChart containerId="latestScenariosGraph" />
```